# laravel-tcpdf displays garbage when hhvm is running

Tags: php, laravel-4, tcpdf, hhvm

I have a project built within laravel, and I use maxxscho/laravel-tcpdf package to generate pdf's.
All is fine, except when I enable hhvm, the previous well generated pdf is now displayed as garbage.

My configuration is:
- Ubuntu server 14.04 x64
- hhvm v3.3.0
- nginx v1.6.2 (the same with apache 2.4.10)
- php 5.6.0
- laravel 4.2.11
- maxxscho/laravel v0.2.3
- tecnic.com/tcpdf v6.0.096

Any known issues of hhvm with tcpdf?
Any suggestions on how to debug this?

I wanted to use hhvm, and this is the only issue I found so far, but off course it's enough to not use it...

Thanks.

Comment: Does the problem happen even if you try to create the simplest PDF possible? What I'm thinking is that if you can create a very simple PDF using this config, then you could comment out all of the code that is populating the PDF object such that you're doing basically the same thing (creating more or less an empty PDF document) and then gradually uncomment lines until you figure out which one is causing the problem.